# spring jpa filtered relationship

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way using jpa/Hibernate to build a filtered relationship?

So let's say this scenario:

A product with one to many prices, of which only one price is "active" at a time.

I'd love to be able to associate a query to get to the related object, something like this:

```
@Formula("select p from Price p where active = 1 and product_id = id)
Price currentPrice;
```

If I recall correctly this type of relationship was quite easy to set up in Active Record (Ruby on Rails), but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Richard..
I seen your problem Like Query problem.

@Formule("SELECT P FROM Price P WHERE P.active=:1 AND Product_Id=:id",Price.class);
    and please set your query parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's right, there doesn't seem to be a second parameter to the Forumla annotation.